# How to find container with combo boxes that has specific values

Tags: extjs

Please refer to ff:

**Main Container:**

```
xtype: 'container',
name: 'mainContainer',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'myXtype',
        name: 'some1'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'myXtype',
        name: 'some2'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'myXtype',
        name: 'some3'
    }
]
```

**myXtype:**

```
Ext.define('blabla.MyXtype', function() {
....
alias: 'widget.myXtype',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combo',
        name: 'combo1'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'combo',
        name: 'combo2'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'combo',
        name: 'combo3'
    }
....
});
```

Now, I want to find the `myXtype` container that contains exact combo's with a specific value. Say, I have values `(test1,test2,test3)` and the ff `myXtype` and their values:

```
some1: { //not this, combo values not matching my values
    combo1: 'not this1'
    combo2: 'not this2'
    combo3: 'not this3'
},
some2: { //not this also, combo3 is null
    combo1: 'test1',
    combo2: 'test2',
    combo3: null
},
some3: { //should be this 1
    combo1: 'test1',
    combo2: 'test2'
    combo3: 'test3'
}
```

I've tried this one but this throws ***`Invalid ComponentQuery selector`*** error:

```
var found = mainContainer.down('![xtype=myXtype] combo[value=test1] combo[value=test2] combo[value=test3]');
```

I know that Extjs `down()` function can take CSS selectors as parameter but unluckily, there is no parent selector in CSS, right?

I've also tried **jQuery**'s `:has()` selector with no luck:

```
var found = mainContainer.down('[xtype=myXtype]:has(combo[value=test1], combo[value=test2], combo[value=test3])')
```

Any help would be very very much appreciated.

**NOTE:** There's the idea to loop foreach `myXtype` then loop again over it's `combo` children and check for their values but I think that is not very optimal. Also, I want an **`ExtJS`** answer.

**EDIT:** I opted to doing a loop, but I will leave this question here for future reference.

***`Cheers!`***

Comment: You can make use of ID`, Also specific  combo have some store hit the store in that case

Comment: no, i cant use ids because `myXtype` are dynamically added to `mainContainer` on-the-fly

Comment: Add a `getValue` method to `myXtype`. Then just do a query to get the xtypes and compare the values in a loop. A loop will be no less efficient than a query, since the query will be doing roughly the same (if not maybe more) work.